# What is the name of this concept I am implementing, and how to in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, roles, multiple-users

I am trying to implement a feature to my project (kind of like a social media site) that could be either basic or complex and I am not sure if I am going to take forever reinventing the wheel or just go on a crazy tangent that won't work. I just need to "check in" so to say.

I am going to use Facebook terminology as an example to simplify the concept but implement similar features with different names. In Facebook you have `Pages` and `Groups`, which are similar yet have slight differences (from now, I will call the collection of these `DataSets`). Both of these can have multiple `admins` or `followers`, which are all `User` roles, and each `User` can have roles for multiple `Groups` and multiple `Pages` (one role per `Group` or `Page`). Then for example, you can click a drop down to change your account to post as a `Page` you are an `admin` for.

Essentially, the concept I am describing is where a single `User` can have a `role` for multiple different types of `DataSets`. For example, a single `User` could follow 30 different `Pages` and 10 different `Groups`, and be an admin for one `Group` and two `Pages`. Does the concept I am describing belong to a particular concept or software design pattern? I am finding it really hard to describe this feature without using Facebook examples.

I have a strategy to implement this type of functionality in Rails, but I feel like using this strategy would be making the problem harder than it is and there is a fancy rails way of doing it, or a Gem, but I just don't know how to research it due to lack of terminology to describe my problem.

Current strategy is:

I have a `Users` table from Devise. `Pages` and `Groups` are each individual models and have their own tables. I have matching database tables to make the many-to-many relationships between `Pages` and `Users`, along with `Groups` and `Users` (e.g. 3 column design, column for the user_id, column for the page_id and the type of relationship such as `admin` or `follower`). Let's call these `Group_User` and `Page_User`. I am being flexible at the moment as I may add more `DataSets` similar to `Page` and `Group`.

Then for the Devise `User` table, I have an extra two columns to track the `DataSet` that the User is an admin for and currently posting as. One column is for the `DataSet` type and the other for the id for this instance (e.g. [Group,1] is stored in these two columns to represent Group with group_id:1 and [Page,3] is used to represent Page with page_id:3). These two columns can be checked when displaying options relevant for `admins` in that `Group`/`Page` and a simple drop down at the top of the site changes the values in these columns to any of the `Pages`/`Groups` the logged in `User` is an `admin` for. This way, one `User` login can take on many `admin` roles and change between these easily as needed.

Is there a better way to do this in Rails, such as a gem or specific design pattern? Or am I on track to implement these features myself? I think I understand the problem but my solution just seems simple/raw and possibly might have unintended consequences later down the track (e.g. it seems database intensive).

One way I was thinking of doing this was making a concern that includes methods to build the relationships and pass in the name of the `DataSet` as an argument, just so I am not rewriting the same methods for `Pages`, then `Groups`, then whatever comes next.

I looked at other solutions such as polymorphic typing (which I think is good for if each user only had one role or only managed relationships for one group or one page) and Single Table Inheritance (but I think my `Pages` and `Groups` might be too different for this to work). I thought about using inheritance as well (e.g. a parent for both `Group` and `Page`) but I am not sure this helps much.

I am just a guy that studied too much computer science and not enough software engineering. Any tips on how to simplify this problem or just a simple "yeah that will work" would be really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are going great in the database design. Once participated in a social media application like yours which had similar type of design. Your design seems much better than the one I worked with. In my opinion this type of applications are supposed to be database extensive.

There are several design patterns used in RoR. One I heavily use is `Service Object Pattern` to maintain thin controller and models. Also it helps me to write reusable class. 
Another one I like is the `Presenter Pattern` to simplify views.

You can have a details look at this [blog post](https://www.sitepoint.com/7-design-patterns-to-refactor-mvc-components-in-rails/) for more design pattern ideas.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will hold off giving it the tick for now incase I get another reply but I am not sure if this is the type of question that has an exact answer.

Comment: Sorry, actually, do you mind me asking to expand on the answer a bit more? Is the concern a good idea or not? Are the other ideas I dismissed (inheritance, STI, polymorphic types) correctly dismissed?